# Fixed header, fixed footer dynamic content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with my dynamic content. So let me explain in a picture:

[image]

So my html looks like:

```
<div id="header"> ... </div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="block"> ... </div>
    <div class="block"> ... </div>
    <div class="block"> ... </div>
    <div class="block"> ... </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"> ... </div>
```

My question: How can I get my container be fluid and the header and footer be fixed? The blocks in the container are set on 50% height and width, so only the container has to be the 100% height (- the fixed header and footer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `box-sizing` property.

Like so:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PGC7D/18/)**

(the example I use here assumes a header of 64px height and footer of 30px height)

### Markup

```
<header>header</header>
 <div class="container">
     <div id="content">
         <div class="block">block1</div><!--
         --><div class="block">block2</div><!--
         --><div class="block">block3</div><!--
         --><div class="block">block4</div>
    </div>    
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

### CSS

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
header,footer,div
{
   width: 100%; 
}
.container
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin: -64px 0 -30px;
    padding: 64px 0 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
}
.block
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
header
{
    height: 64px;
    background: purple;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
footer
{
    height: 30px;
    background: gray;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Use `float` as Haidy is asking it to be fluid @Danield

Comment: Allright, got this working now, is it also possible when my footer is smaller then the header?

Comment: @Haidy , I updated my answer and fiddle with a footer height less than the header height

Comment: @Danield Thanks mate! Works like a boss ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like this

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzmaK/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header{
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}
#footer{
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
#container{
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    width:100%;
    top:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.block{
    width:50%;
    background-color:gray;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't work? also the jsfiddle not? The container is small and not overlapping the other white space?

Answer (score 2):

Use `float` to make it fluid desgins.Be Caution about `width` part when border or padding is added. Because those are calculated with `width`. As Danield mentioned you can use [Box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
Obviously Measurements should be in percentage to make it responsive Or alternatively you can write [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with `twitter-bootstrap`. Here is a more Bootstrap friendly approach:

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/render/88297

**Code:** http://bootply.com/88297

This uses a somewhat standard BS header/nav and fixed footer. Then the center container uses `table`,`table-row` and `table-cell` to size the center boxes accordingly at 50/50.

```
.center-container {
  height:100%;
  display: table;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.center-row {
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.center-row > div {
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid #eee
}
```